# Unable to rename folders through Explorer in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, rename

I can copy, move, create, and delete them. I can rename them using the REN command from a command prompt. I cannot rename folders through Windows Explorer anywhere on my machine, including on other drives.

When I try to do so, I receive an error titled "Rename Folder" that says "Can't find the specified file. Make sure you specify the correct path and file name." Then when I click Try Again or Cancel, I get another error titled "Rename" that says "The file or folder does not exist."

As far as I can tell, nothing else is wrong with my computer, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to fix this problem. I don't know for sure if superuser is the right place to ask this question, but feel free to redirect me.

**Summary of Failed Attempts:**

1. Booted into Safe Mode
2. Made a New User Account
3. System Restore Point (two days ago, 9 days ago)
4. Deleting / Restoring / Modifying FolderDescriptions registry entries
5. SFC /scannow
6. Removing windows update KB2984006
7. Scanned for viruses using Nod32
8. Scanned for malware using MalwareBytes

**Details:**

Tried rolling back to two different system restore points, both immediately before I observed the problem and one release prior to that.

Tried restoring FolderDescriptions registry entries as found here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/windows8/comments/1xexqg/cant_rename_a_folder_in_windows_81_any_ideas_my/

Booting in safe mode as suggested here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/cant-rename-or-move-folders-in-81/0e2209a2-bb29-4f01-9830-c175de3420f3

SFC /scannow as suggested here:
http://www.networksteve.com/windows/topic.php/KB2911106_regression_bug:_Cannot_rename_any_folders_in_Windows_E/?TopicId=61599&Posts=1

Tried removing registry keys and windows update KB2984006 as suggested here:
http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2014/11/cannot-renamemove-folders-and-files-in-windows-8-1.html

Tried exporting folderdescriptions from other machine and importing as suggested here:
http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/43167-unable-rename-folders-windows-8-1-a.html

Compared my exported registry with other machine's exported registry for both:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions
```

My FolderDescriptions branch of the registry in both cases are binary equal to those exported from my wife's Windows 8.1 laptop which works fine.

Comment: Request for clarification: is the issue with *all* folders, or just particular ones such as those in the Windows folder? Also, have you tried alternate directory tools, such as QDir ( http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir ), to see if they have the same issue? If they're OK, it might be that Explorer is damaged.

Comment: It appears to be with all folders, on any drive location, from any user. Interesting suggestion about alternate directory tools. QDir has no problems renaming folders, so definitely seems Explorer-related.

Comment: oops... since Explorer is an intrinsic part of Windows, I do not know of any quick fix for the issue; it appears you've tried the most prudent repairs, particularly SFC (as Administrator, I assume). Though you *could* try reinstalling Windows, that would lose most customization you've done and require a plethora of updates. If defaulting to QDir or alternative file manager is not acceptable, perhaps someone else here can help resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the thought! I think for the moment I'm working around it rather than breaking down and reinstalling Windows, partially because I see so many posts of other people who have that problem that eventually just gave up and reinstalled, which means that there is no real fix to be found in their threads! I feel like if I can tough it out and find a solution, maybe someone else can benefit.

Comment: You might get away with a refresh instead of a full reinstall.

Comment: I have this same problem.  I can even rename folders using the command prompt without administrative priveleges, but cannot rename any folder on any drive using explorer.

Comment: If you can rename from a command prompt, but not through Explorer, that would *scream* to me the possibility of a *misbehaving* antivirus utility with hooks through Explorer *or* a stealth virus that is escaping scans. I would go through not merely safe mode, but to fire up the System COnfiguration tool and turn off everything I didn't *know* I needed - some of those things come up even in safe mode.

Comment: I shut down WebRoot protection and that didn't help.  I have already removed everything I cannot identify from startup using Autoruns.  I'm chasing another lead right now.  Will post results.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate Do you have Acrobat installed by any chance ?

Comment: This PC was just rebuilt by our tech contractor.  That was the first thing I uninstalled.  So it *was* there.

Comment: Do you happen to have a utility called "odrive"?

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate No I don't have `odrive`. Did you remove Acrobat using the [cleaner](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/acrobatcleaner.html) or from add & remove section ? Also is uninstalling Webroot an option ?

Comment: I removed it from Programs & Features.  I could uninstall webroot, but our tech would not be happy :)

Comment: You could ask them to re-install it anyways. We do this all the time. I would use uninstaller for such scenarios

Comment: I should also mention this is Windows 10 for me.  Same symptoms though.

Comment: I have the same problem on Win 8.1 and it is driving me insane

Comment: @gyozokudor did you try my solution below?

Comment: no, I didn't like the side effects. I rename my folders from total commander or command line. For some reason it works from there.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, after trying everything in this thread and a few additional posts on reddit and MS forums, I finally found something that works.

This [Sevenforums - Default File Type Associations tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) has an entry for `Directory - Directory protocol associations` which links to [this reg file](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/122125d1312706239-default-file-type-associations-restore-default_directory.reg).  I ran it then rebooted and now I can rename folders!  [Here is a pastebin of the reg file](http://pastebin.com/YmMMmj9C) if you're paranoid like me and want to glance over it first.

It seems it may have come with some [slight side effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x15S.png), but I'll take it.

Comment: Alas, I must admit that I ultimately ended up upgrading to Windows 10, WHICH STILL DIDN'T FIX THE PROBLEM. So I did a full reinstall from scratch, and that did fix the problem. So, I cannot test your solution, but I'm glad you at least found something that works!

Comment: Is this solution also available *without* the side effects? :)

Comment: I'm not positive this caused that but I was able to fix it too.

Comment: This just happened to me AGAIN and this time the reg file did not fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I have three suggestions. Try out and let me know:

1. Copy the explorer.exe from your wife's computer into yours using a differnt file manager or cmd prompt after ending the explorer.exe process from task manager. This will solve the problem if it occurred because the executable was wonky.
2. Get the latest possible genuine Windows 8.1 image, mount it in a virtual drive from within Windows itself and choose to upgrade.
3. Refresh your Windows installation. Follow the instructions from Microsoft [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc). **BE CAREFUL. YOU WILL LOSE INSTALLED APPS AND APPDATA**

Once solved, I would suggest either using the default, Microsoft Security Essentials or any other good antivirus with minimal disruptive behavior.

Comment: I don't think it's a virus. It's almost certainly registry corruption.

Comment: Why would you want to reinstall windows for this?

Comment: option 2 won't reinstall, but will probably solve any corruption in Windows files. It keeps all files, settings and softwares
option 3 is a kind-of "reinstall" step but it is a drastic one for when you've tried everything but nothing works.

Answer (score -1):

I just posted on this web site (3rd Sept 2016):

"Windows 10 file explorer won't rename any New folder created" with link below

[Windows 10 file explorer won't rename any New folder created](https://superuser.com/questions/1120563/windows-10-file-explorer-wont-rename-any-new-folder-created)

Trying to better document this issue, I found this post link appearing on the right! Brilliant how the links are automatically suggested. I am just amazed by this web site.

So, my W10 issue is very similar to this "old" one.
Root cause unknown until know. 
It is repetitive for me (happened on more than one of my personal PCs after upgrading to W10).

Based on at least three web threads on this very issue, it does not look like a random corruption of the registry but something that happens in a specific setting up context (which one precisely I don't know - I suspect without verification that as a user, I systematically relocate all windows user folders, which may have caused a problem in the upgrade W7->W10)), indeed requiring a registry repair to mitigate.

I guess that W8.1 and W10 deeper testing on it will highlight this problem at some point, which will trigger the production of a fix at MS in due course.

The link above points to the registry keys I & others changed to solve the issue, at least for my config. It has to be tested to see if it also relevant here and can be generalised.

I am still concerned as I don't know what I did & what are the potential side effects. Only it worked. So, I would appreciate input from engineers with knowledge on this just to reassure that this solution is not foolish.

I just saw that someone (w32sh) confirmed firmly - without any deeper insight as to what happened - the more elaborate solution that can be found on 
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-rename-move-folders-windows-10/

From memory, the solution proposed fully rebuilds (correctly populates) the  keys that need to be rebuilt instead of simply deleting 5 keys as I did.

acontrario
Brussels

Comment: So what is the solution to the author's problem?

Comment: Please see amended post this time with hyperlink. Sorry for that.

Comment: At least this is closer to an answer.  If you want to hear more feedback on it, come into the Root Access, when you have enough reputation.